# Access token for Facebook / Instagram in client side JS function

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, access-token, facebook-access-token

I am using some JS functions as Html scripts which loads images from the user FB / Instagram account. They work correctly, but I am afraid they are not secure: the secret user access token  (first line in each function) is visible in the js client side.

```
function LoadIntagramContent(event){
  var token = XXXXXXXXXXXXXX;
  event.preventDefault();
  var userid = instagram_user_id;
  var num_photos = 20; 
  var data_imgs_srcs = [];

  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/' + userid + '/media/recent', 
    async: false,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {access_token: token, count: num_photos},
    success: function(data){
      $(".social-img-wrapper").remove();
        for( x in data.data ){ //The images come as numerated JSON
        var insta_extra_info = JSON.stringify( {'digsrc': 'instagram', 'url': data.data[x].link } )
            $('#social-uploads .modal-body').append('<div class="social-img-wrapper"><img class="social-img img-fluid" src="'+ data.data[x].images.standard_resolution.url+'" onclick=" $(this).toggleClass(\'social-img-selected\');" ></div>');
        $('#social-uploads').modal()
        }
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log(data); // send the error notifications to console
    }
  });
}

function LoadFacebookContent(event){
  var token = XXXXXXXXXXX;
  event.preventDefault();
  FB.api(
  '/me',
  'GET', {
    "fields": "id,name,photos{album,alt_text,created_time,id,picture,webp_images,link}",
    "access_token" : token,
  },
  function(response) {
    console.log("FB DATA ES: ")
    console.log(response)
    $(".social-img-wrapper").remove();
    var fb_data = response.photos.data;
    for( let x of fb_data ){ //The images come as array
      var fb_extra_info = JSON.stringify( {'digsrc': 'facebook', 'url': x.link } )
      $('#social-uploads .modal-body').append('<div class="social-img-wrapper"><img class="social-img img-fluid" src="'+ x.picture + '" onclick=" $(this).toggleClass(\'social-img-selected\');" ></div>');
      $('#social-uploads').modal()
    }
  });
}
```

I wonder how to fix this issue, since the Facebook API documentation explicitly warns about this:

> One parameter of note is access_token which you can use to make an API call with a Page access token. App access tokens should never be used in this SDK as it is client-side, and your app secret would be exposed.

I hope there is a minimal easy solution which does not require major changes in client side. I am using Django as server side framework with Heroku, but I did not tag this question for both because I hope there is an independent easier solution which doesn´t require them.

Answer (score 0):

As considering Facebook API doc's warning or by our common sense, it is better not to use access tokens on client side scripting languages.

To solve this..

1) Create a server side function to access Facebook/Instagram data (You can use Facebook SDK of your back-end language for the purpose)

PHP example

```
function getInsta($username)
{
     /*
        Some codes
      */
        $instaResult = file_get_contents('https://www.instagram.com/'.$username.'/media/');
    $insta = json_decode($instaResult);
    /*
       some code if required
    */

    return $formated_results_from_insta;
}
```

2) Create a route (API URL) to this function (I don't know which bakcend language you are using)

3) Call to this created URL from your ajax instead of direct access to instagram.

Hence access_token will be safe at server side, and you will get the desired results.